# Plane Motion of Rigid Bodies: Work and Energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

[image]

"A 100-kg spool with inner and outer radii 300 and 600 mm, respectively, is initially at rest on a 45° incline with a coefficient of kinetic friction of 0.15. Upon moving down the incline by 2 meters, how much work is done by friction? The spool's cord is parallel to the incline at all times."

Since the frictional force is constant and is easily solved by getting the normal force, the only difficulty I find is getting the distance for which the frictional force acts.

My solution gives out 4 meters, because the point of contact with the incline is on a circle twice the radius, so if the center travels 2 meters, the inner circle rotates through 2 meters of circumference, and the outer rotates by 4 meters.

But my professor says it's 6 meters, since the rope's contact point serves as an instantaneous center of rotation, and thus if the center moves by 2 meters, the incline contact point moves by thrice as much.

I don't know which is correct. I find it hard to understand how it could have rotated through 6 meters of circumference in the 2 meters its center has moved.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

As you might expect your professor is correct.

If you were given the diagram below and asked how far the top of the wheel moved you would produce an answer of $6 \, \rm m$.

[image]

The string-wheel contact point is stationary all you do not have shown in your diagram is the bit of string which will be visible as the wheel unwinds.